# Loop through JSON from jquery getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here is the code:

```
        $.getJSON( base_url + '/ajax/sortListings.php', { sort: sort }, function( data ) {
            $.each(data, function(i, json) {

                $( '#listings' ).append($('<div>').load( base_url + '/partialviews/listingAdminPrev.php', {
                  id: json.id,
                  name: json.name,
                  logo: encodeURIComponent(json.logo),
                  address: json.address,
                  city: json.city,
                  state: json.state,
                  zip: json.zip,
                  phone: json.phone,
                  email: json.email,
                  web_link: encodeURIComponent(json.web_link),
                  services: json.services,
                  category: json.category,
                  status: json.status,
                  created: json.created
                } ));

            });
        });
```

When I manually go to the sortListings.php file and turn the $_POST variables to $_GET, it works fine. So nothing is wrong with the file. But here it is anyway:

```
include_once('../../app/scripts/config.php');
$listingObject = Listing::getInstance();

$results = $listingObject->get_listings($_POST['sort']);

echo json_encode($results);
```

That file returns this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "32",
        "user_id": "32",
        "logo": "32_52a0960ba791c.jpg",
        "name": "Anthony Thomas Advertising",
        "address": "380 S. Main St.",
        "city": "Akron",
        "state": "AL",
        "zip": "44311",
        "phone": "3302536888",
        "email": "wayne@anthonythomas.com",
        "web_link": "http://www.aol.com",
        "status": "1",
        "services": "dfhfdhdfh",
        "category": "1",
        "created": "2013-12-05 09:32:56"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "user_id": "10",
        "logo": "10_529f96001390d.png",
        "name": "Graphic Installation Services",
        "address": "2808 Broadway Blvd Unit 1",
        "city": "Monroeville",
        "state": "PA",
        "zip": "15146",
        "phone": "3306599898",
        "email": "graphic@graphicinstallationservices.com",
        "web_link": "",
        "status": "4",
        "services": "Graphic installation services",
        "category": "1",
        "created": "2013-12-04 11:35:11"
    },
    {
        "id": "21",
        "user_id": "10",
        "logo": "10_529f9c1a8375d.png",
        "name": "Intellect Productions",
        "address": "2915 13th St NW",
        "city": "Canton",
        "state": "OH",
        "zip": "44708",
        "phone": "3309334833",
        "email": "mouseywings@live.com",
        "web_link": "",
        "status": "1",
        "services": "Car Wrap Installations by Intellect Productions",
        "category": "1",
        "created": "2013-12-04 15:20:15"
    },
    {
        "id": "19",
        "user_id": "10",
        "logo": "10_529cf170b08d7.png",
        "name": "International Installations Inc",
        "address": "833 Wooster Rd N",
        "city": "Barberton",
        "state": "OH",
        "zip": "44203",
        "phone": "3306586526",
        "email": "internationalinstallers@internationinstallers.com",
        "web_link": "http://intellectproductions.com/",
        "status": "1",
        "services": "We install:\r\n· vehicle wraps\r\n· decals\r\n· vehicle lettering\r\n· banners\r\n· billboards\r\n· murals\r\nInternational Image Application Inc. is PDAA certified. We strive to deliver a constant flow of high quality work using best materials in the business, and unsurpassed skill. This ensures that our clients receive value for money, and more bang for their buck!\r\nAnd to ensure that our clients continue to receive the highest quality of work possible, we stay on top of technological trends, new materials, and installation techniques. This dedication to continued education has resulted in many clients coming back again and again.\r\nFrom a simple vehicle wraps installation to an entire ad campaign or fleet, International Image Application Inc. is your destination for precision graphics installation on virtually any medium.",
        "category": "1",
        "created": "2013-12-04 10:32:52"
    }
]
```

Which is 5 listings.. so it's pulling the data fine. However, nothing is working beyond the $.each().. I even tried alerting stuff and nothing.

No console errors are thrown either..

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hit on your problem.  You are expecting the `sort` parameter in `$_POST` while you are calling `getJSON()` which executes a GET.

Make up your mind whether you want to use GET or POST and be consistent.

My guess is you also need to put better error handling in `Listing::get_listings()` method to provide useful errors when you are not getting the data your expect passed to it.

Comment: How do you grab if it returns false with the json call? That's the part that throws me off. Pure PHP is easy to throw errors and grab. I just don't really understand how to with JSON since I never use this. If that function returns false, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: And the get_listings() has a default parameter of 'name' so .. didn't really need debugging D:

Comment: @Peanut What you should probably do is inspect the database results. If there is no result to be sent for the request, simply return some sort of indicator to the calling AJAX. This could be something like `{"error":"Some error message"}`.  Alternately you could return a non-200 (i.e. 500) HTTP response code which which would trigger allow error handling callback function to be invoked rather than success callback.